# create primary key ROW_NUMBER() over function sql teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I want to create a primary key in my `select` statement. I read that I can use `ROW_NUMBER() over` function. But as it is going to be primary key, i don't have any columns for `over` or `partition by`. I tried using just `select row_number() as PK`but that throws error `[3706] syntax error: expected something between ( and as keyword`.

how could I resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You would need an `over` clause.  I'm not sure if the `order by` is optional in Teradata (I don't have a version on hand):

```
row_number() over ()
row_number() over (order by <some column here>)
```

Comment: `row_number() over ()` throws error that `expect something between ( and ) `

Comment: You have to have an order by, partition by is optional.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create a auto generated number which you can then use as a primary index for good distribution across the AMPs in Teradata nodes (which you refer to as PK in select statement) ?

If so, and if you dont want to use the IDENTITY COLUMN data type to do that for you (pros and cons exist), then you could generate such a auto number to be used as PI in Teardata by simply using a csum function. (Mind you, your target table must not be too large i.e. more than a few hundred thousands to a million)

```
SELECT 
   mx.max_id + csum(1,1) as PI_column
  ,src.columnABC
from 
  source_table src
cross join 
  (SELECT max(id) as max_id from target_table) as mx
group by 1,2
order by 1;
```

This will generate a new PI/PK/Unique ID column to be used for PI with good distribution for every unique combination of ColumnABC.

Hope this helps.

If my "if" statement at the beginning was not true, then please explain further what are you trying to do and i will be happy to help you with that.

Comment: Are you trying to create a auto generated number which you can then use as a primary index for good distribution across the AMPs in Teradata nodes (which you refer to as PK in select statement) ?  - YES

Comment: Then please follow the example I just gave. Generate new keys by using a csum function & inserting that into a lookup table. Then select from your source / stage table left outer join to your lookup table to get the generated keys and load them into your target table.

Comment: Could you indent your code properly? My table has more than million rows - would that change the solution?

Comment: code has been indented. Not a regular stack overflow user :) pardon my lack of interface skills here. 

Whats your total number of rows? Whats your Teradata nodes capacity (e.g. 4 node XXX series)

In anycase, if you have hundreds of millions of rows, I would wonder why did you need to generate PK / PI like this for such a data set. Perhaps there is a data modeling technique that first needs to break this data set into more granular 3NF model that would be a better storage solution as well as better performance for query access.

Comment: i have around 2 Million rows. what is `target_table`? I assume `source_table ` has the data, is that correct? I have a table from which i will be pulling data and then in my select statement want to create a primary key. So there is only one source table

Comment: `CSUM(1,1)` is a very bad solution as it results in a single AMP processing all the data. Must use a `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY any_column_with_good_distibution)`

Comment: what do you mean by `any_column_with_good_distibution`? @dnoeth

Comment: @user2543622: Any column with not too many rows per value, e.g. an INTEGER with up to a few hundreds rows/value (same as Gordon's `<some column here>`)

Comment: @dnoeth indeed, thats why I asked him if the table is small. row number is a better option.